# VueJs: Accessing data from within embedded component using inline-template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've got this component, which looks something like this

```js
<template>
    <form-wrapper
        v-show="show"
          :request-action="action"
        inline-template
        v-cloak
    >
      <form @submit.prevent="submit()" novalidate>

        <html-editor
            v-model="fields.body"
            id="body"
            :contents-css="editorStyles"
        ></html-editor>

      </form>

    </form-wrapper>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            show: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: true
            },
            action: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            editorStyles: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see the main component (file of which content you can see) has 2 other components embedded: `form-wrapper` and `html-editor` - second one being inside of the `form-wrapper`, which uses `inline-template`.

The problem I have is that `editorStyles` is not accessible from within the `form-wrapper` inline template.

My question is - how can I make this property available within the `inline-template` of the `form-wrapper` component (other than adding it as a property of `form-wrapper`).

Comment: Is there a reason you are choosing `inline-template` over `slot`?

Comment: Yes - there was a good reason (can't remember exactly), but from what I can remember - it simply didn't work with the `slot` the way I was using it.

Comment: That being the case, I don't think there is a way to do what you want. The elements inside the form wrapper *are* the template for the form wrapper. The template will be compiled before properties are bound, before even the component is instantiated. Unless something like `:contents-css="$parent.editorStyles"` works.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks @BertEvans - I'll add `customProperties` property to the `form-wrapper` as `Object` and bind it this way.

Comment: I added a little more to that comment that *might* work. Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this *does* appear to work. Feels a little icky, but there you have it :)

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("html-editor", {
 props:["contentsCss"],
 template:`<div>From Parent: {{contentsCss}}</div>`
})

Vue.component("form-wrapper", {
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    editorStyles: "Hello World"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form-wrapper inline-template>
    <html-editor :contents-css="$parent.editorStyles"></html-editor>
  </form-wrapper>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Bert Evans - it does work indeed, but as you say - it seems a bit icky :). I think I stick with the custom property on the `form-wrapper`, but I'll accept your answer as it does answer my question - thanks again for your help.